# How can I provide search for a GitHub wiki hosted in a private (organizational) repo?

Tags: github, search

We have a lot of engineering documentation stored in a shared repository wiki. The repo itself, though, is private (i.e. part of an organization).

Although there is functionality in the wiki to search for page names, how can we search for keywords?

Using the general repo search only searches code and issues, and even advanced search doesn't appear to provide this functionality. We are open to suggestions including:

- running a remote server that could index the wiki
- having a script installed somewhere that we could link to from a search box + submit button on the wiki

However we are not interested in making users install browser scripts (like https://github.com/linyows/github-wiki-search) as non-engineers will use this search feature as well.

I suppose one possible answer is to re-write the code from the above link to be stand-alone but I would have thought someone would have already tackled this by now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Github to do this. You may be better of using a 3rd party wiki software such as [Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Comment: Before trying to migrate a bunch of documents to a new wiki, I'm hoping to explore what other options might be available. I'm leaning towards having a separate server that can clone the repo, index the wiki, and provide an endpoint for searching.